# Disambiguating [activerecord] vs [rails-activerecord], [actionmailer] & CO

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

The [ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) framework is composed by several different gems (libs):

- ActiveRecord
- ActionMailer
- ActionPack
- and more

Unfortunately, ActiveRecord is also a design pattern. The result is that the tag [activerecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/activerecord) is very confusing as of today. The majority of discussions are actually related to the Rails library. However, [rails-activerecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rails-activerecord) was also created, probably trying to disambiguate the meaning of the tag.

A similar confusion is arising for [actionmailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actionmailer), where apparently there is both a Ruby and .NET library called `actionmailer`.

Then we have [actionpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actionpack), [actionview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actionview), [actioncable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actioncable), [activemodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/activemodel), [activesupport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/activesupport) and, of course, [ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails).

The current state is not only very confusing, but it will become even harder to manage for Documentation as both the `activerecord` and `actionmailer` tag will likely attract different kind of contents.

How do you suggest to handle it? Should `rails-activerecord` and `activerecord` be merged? What about the disambiguation between the topics? And what about `actionmailer`?

Comment: Dear down-voter, do you care to explain the reason of it?